# Creating timestamp as key value

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a dictionary in python which consists of timestamp as key value and a transaction amount at that time. I want to then add the total sum of the transaction amount after a end time value.
I have no clue how to do it. As anyone would have guessed that I am a beginner.

Comment: you've just given a description, with nothing else to work with. What have you tried so far? Please include the code and some examples to better describe the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can work with timestamps via the `datetime` module:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now() # a datetime representing the current time
later = datetime.datetime(year=2025, month=1, day=1, hour=12) # noon on 2025-01-01
```

You can add these as dictionary keys just fine:

```
time_to_amount = {
    now: 5,
    later: 10
}
```

And you can sum the amounts:

```
total = sum(time_to_amount.values())
```

You can of course add the total to the dictionary in the normal way, but note that python dictionaries are not ordered — you can look into the `ordereddict` module if you need that. If you are ok with just accessing it via timestamp then you can just

```
time_to_amount[datetime.datetime.now()] = total
```

Comment: To only sum transaction amounts after a certain date `end` you can use something like `sum(amount for stamp, amount in time_to_amount.items() if amount > end)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try this approach and surely include the code next time. I so glad to see this community responsiveness. This was my first time to ask for help, and I am very encouraged to get a response so fast. Thanks

Comment: @M.Waseem if this answer helped you with your problem, please click the checkmark by it so others know it's been answered. Thanks! :)

Comment: I am trying this code, however since I am a novice, no luck. I am first trying to populate the dictionary with time as key value starting at 8 am each day and transaction amount taken place at that time.

Comment: @M.Waseem I think your best bet would be to close this question out by clicking the check mark, and then posting a new question with the code you are trying and the error you are getting (or describing how the result isn't what you expected.) If you do that, reply here and I'll be happy to help.